# How to pivot to an adjacent vertex in simplex method

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming, simplex

In the simplex method, we need to move from one vertex of the polyhedron to an adjacent one. Suppose the polyhedron is $P=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid Ax=b,x\geq0\}$ with rank$A=m<n$.  For a nondegenerate vertex, it has $n$ adjacent vertices. In the simplex textbooks, they say that to get an adjacent vertex, we just need to switch one basic variable with one nonbasic variable. However, there are $m$ basic variables and $n−m$ nonbasic variables. Therefore, the total number of such switches is $m(n−m)$. But I know, there are only $n$ adjacent vertices. So am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Since every vertex of $P$ is basic feasible solution and vice versa, a non-degenerate vertex has exactly $m(n-m)$ adjacent vertices. I don't know what gave you the idea that this number is $n$, but this is simply not the case.

Comment: I guess I'm mistaken since all my intuitions actually come from polypedra in the form $P= \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid A x\leq b \}$. If $n=2$, then each nondegenerate vertex has two adjacent ones (e.g $0\leq x_1, x_2 \leq 1$ and $x_1 +x_2\leq 1$). However, if I include slack variables in $x$ in order to get the standard form (in linear program), I'm enlarging the dimension of $x$.